# Heroku : unable to backup sql database

Tags: mysql, bash, heroku, heroku-cli

I want to backup my JawsDB database on Heroku. Here's what the docs says : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#backup-existing-database
What I've done :

- Install Heroku CLI
- Add two mysql buildpacks (https://github.com/daetherius/heroku-buildpack-mysql & https://github.com/gaumire/heroku-buildpack-mysql)
- Run `heroku run mysqldump -h OLDHOST -u OLDUSER -pOLDPASS OLDDATABASE > backup.sql --app MYAPP`

And I end up with a backup.sql on my local directory, which only contains `bash: mysqldump: command not found`

I also wanted to create a bash file in order to try to dump my database and I do not know how to do that with Heroku CLI. I installed a nano plugin with `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ehryk/heroku-nano`, but obtains `no plugins installed` when I run `heroku plugins`.

Comment: What you ran isn't what the docs are talking about. The `mysqldump` is not available to you on the heroku site, which is where you're trying to run it. The docs are talking about running `mysqldump` locally on your machine (where, presumably, `mysqldump` is installed).